# What are the two numbers in top left of uap app using VS2015 and Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Win 10 Preview and VS 2015. I created a new uap blank app and ran it and I get a Window with two numbers on the top left, eg 000 000
If I add a button to the app (and move it away from the obscuring numbers) and then click the button, the numbers change in what seems to me a random way, eg 020 001.

What is going on?

Answer (score 7):

I have now found that these numbers disappear if you set

```
this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false
```

in OnLaunched.
This is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh701818(v=win.10).aspx?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter)%3bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3dv4.5.1)%3bk(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Not that this means anything to me.

Comment: You probably ought to get your machine checked if they disappear when you use *true*.

Answer (score 3):

It's the frame counter turned on by the following code snippet in your App.xaml.cs:

```
#if DEBUG
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
    }
#endif
```

source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a33a634c-5c68-44b4-8fca-8eb5a263d145/misterious-numbers-being-displayed-in-upper-left-and-right-corners-of-the-screen?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 1):

These are debug informations, they will not show up if you build in release mode.

Left number is the FPS counter for your app, right number is the CPU usage for each frame in % (only for computations in the UI thread).

But the MSDN page you linked provided a full explanation.